# What is the preferable memory layout of Algebraic Data Types?

Tags: llvm, algebraic-data-types

Algebraic Data Types (ADTs) are types consisting of unit, product and sum types with possible recursion.

Consider a simple ADT in Haskell:

```hs
data Tree = Empty
          | Leaf Int
          | Node Tree Tree
```

Or a different example in Rust:

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
}
```

How does Haskell (garbage collected) and Rust (not garbage collected) actually represent these in memory, and how should they be represented?

I'm primarily interested in the non garbage collected case which is simpler, but the solution must be workable both for the heap and stack if non-garbage collected, like for Rust.

Representations in LLVM, or C/C++ are what I'm interested in.

Using the second example, I can think of two options:

Option 1, using unions:

```c
enum MCtor { CQ, CCC, CM, CW  };

struct Message {
    enum MCtor ctor;
    union {
        void*; /* Quit */
        struct { int r; int g; int b; } /* ChangeColor */
        struct { int x; int y; } /* Move */
        struct { char* str; } /* Write */
    };
};
```

Option 2, using separate allocation, `void*` and (bit)casts:

```c
enum MCtor { CQ, CCC, CM, CW  };

typedef struct { int r; int g; int b; } ChangeColor;
typedef struct { int x; int y; } Move;
typedef struct { char* str; } Write;

struct Message {
    enum MCtor ctor;
    void* data;
};
```

Pattern matching is then simply a matter of `switch` on `msg -> ctor`.

Which one is preferable, especially considering recursive types?

Off the top of my head, I guess that the locality of the first one is better and that it avoids loads, while it might use more memory... So the second option has a better memory footprint but worse performance...?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as *too broad*. You are asking which implementation detail is the best, but there's far too many variables. What machine architecture(s) are you targeting (cache alignment and padding are sure to come into play)? Are you trying to optimize for speed or memory usage? I'd expect it to also depend on what kinds of things will be stored; is everything in your language represented as a pointer?

Comment: Note that Rust *doesn't* directly allow recursive type definitions. If it did, the size of the struct would be infinite. It requires that you add a layer of indirection via a reference or heap-allocated storage.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Not sure if C++ allows anonymous `struct`/`union` members. And your question is primarily opinion based and too broad (pick one). Any is a valid close reason.

Comment: @Olaf I've read that they're not allowed in c++ indeed.

Comment: `void*` is not appropriate for `Quit`; it might make the `union` unnecessarily larger. It holds no data, so just have no value in the `union` for it. Also, you're skipping an extra possibility of having `data` be a pointer to a union. (i.e., `typedef union { struct ... changecolor; ...} msg_data` ... `typedef message { enum ...; msg_data *data; }`).

Comment: @iharob: The snippets smell anyway. `void *;` makes not even sense - even iff it was allowed in C.

Comment: Wow... These were a fast bunch of comments...
I'm fully aware that Rust doesn't directly allow recursive type defs. This is why in the second example, I have an Indirection `void*` which the compiler will interpret with the appropriate stuff. C/C++ refers to "C or C++"... And the snippets are just for prototyping the idea... I copied most of it from wikipedia and modified. I'm writing a compiler, so I'm not actually going to write it in C, but rather LLVM... @Shepmaster Well, I'm also interested in a discussion of the various tradeoffs in addition to how GHC and rustc does it.

Comment: @Shepmaster The likely archs are x86 and ARM, but since I'm compiling to LLVM I really don't know what arch I'm targeting.

Comment: As @iharob clarified, this is not valid in C++. Anyway, a sane programmer would use a different approach anyway in C++ than in C.

Comment: @Olaf This question is not about how to do it specifically in C or C++ - one of these was just used to convey my idea, and since I copied from Wiki, blame Wiki... you can consider them being pseudocode. It is much more interesting to me what happens in VM assembly like LLVM than the details of C vs. C++ which are completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Ok, removed the wrong tag then. Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: It sounds like this is just a discriminated union, isn't it? Sums are (disjoint) unions, and products are tuples.

Comment: @KerrekSB formally yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union In fact, that is where I took the C/C++ example from and altered... While tagged unions have a tag for which product type to use, how to represent the data part is what I'm mostly asking about... For example, should one allocate for the biggest (sizeof) product type in the sum type? Or should one allocate exactly as many bytes needed for the specific product type (constructor) used?

Comment: @Centril: I think you're confusing products and sums. The alternatives (or "variant members") in a union are *summands*, not factors. Yes, you'd use something like [`std::aligned_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) to provide storage for the active member.

Comment: @KerrekSB But... in an ADT, isn't each constructor a product type? I get that the product type is a summand inside the sum type, but the individual members of the tuple are factors, no?

Comment: @Centril: The ADT isn't a tuple, though, it's a union: It's *one of* empy, leaf, or node, and not "all of". Only the node is a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources for explaining how GHC implements data structures:

- Johan Tibell's talk at ZuriHac 2015 [(video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pDUq0nNjhI) [(slides)](http://www.slideshare.net/tibbe/highperformance-haskell) (talk starts at slide 42)
- [GHC Commentary: The Layout of Heap Objects](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects#DataConstructors)

Comment: Neat, anything on how `rustc` does it perhaps?

Comment: Let me go become an expert in Rust now :-)

Comment: I realized that the second option is actually not possible to use on the stack if you return, because then the stack allocated data field will be deallocated... Rust allocates for the biggest variant like the first option in my question, which is demonstrated using: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7cc0c81c888d4c61d952512fea05667a which yields `%Message = type { i8, [7 x i8], [4 x i64] }`